# Diseño de clase orientado a reusabilidad en Spring (Action, Service, DAO)

Tags: java, spring, buenas-prácticas

Estoy trabajando con Java sobre Spring Framework y Hibernate. Tengo una clase que obtiene datos de un archivo digamos CSV, estos datos serán posteriormente convertidos a entidades de Hibernate e insertados en una capa de Services del software. Actualmente el primer paso es obtener los datos en un Map que posteriormente será convertido a una Entity. Debido a que el archivo no contará con todos los datos requeridos para el entity, y algunos de estos datos son consultados desde la BD en la capa de servicios. Me preguntó si es correcto que esta clase que obtiene los datos del CSV continue regresando un Map con solo los datos obtenidos del archivo, o en su lugar regresar el Entity incompleto y que este sea completado con los datos faltantes en la capa de Services.

Ejemplo Actual.

```
    //Imagine the setter and getters
public class FileManager(){
    public Map<String, String> getUserFromFile(InputStream inputStream){
        //............
        //Some implementation to get de username and email from file
        userMap.put("username", username);
        userMap.put("email",email);
        return userMap;
    }
}

public class UserService(){

    private RoleService roleService; //Injected
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    private User convertToUser(Map<String,String> userMap){
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(userMap.get("username"));
        user.setEmail(userMap.get("email"));
        user.setRole(roleService.getDefault());
        return user;
    }

    public User addFromExcel(InputStream inputStream){
        FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
        User user = convertToUser(fileManager.getUserFromFile(inputStream));
        return add(user);
    }

    public User add(User user){
        return userDAO.add(user);
    }
}

public class UserAction(){

    private UserService userSer;
    private File loadedFile; //File from the request form
    private User user; //passed as response

    public String add(){
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStreamYeah(file);
        user = userSer.addFromExcel(inputStream);
        return "new";
    }
}
```

Me gustaría saber cual podría ser la mejor opción teniendo en cuenta re usabilidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que tienes en mente es la reusabilidad, la solución es obvia: sigue usando un Map. De hecho, yo intentaría que esa clase fuese aún más genérica, con dos posibilidades:

### El fichero incluye el nombre de las columnas

No ocurre siempre pero a menudo tenemos algo como

```
"id", "name", "phone"
7592,"Menganito","967000000"
7593,"Patito","967002000"
```

Con lo que podrías leer la primera línea para saber qué elementos (keys) va a tener tu Map y sus valores.

### El fichero NO incluye el nombre de las columnas

En este caso tu FileManager podría recibir en el constructor dos valores:

- El fichero a leer.
- Una lista con el nombre de las columnas.

De este modo tendrías un FileManager que puede leer cualquier tipo de CSV.

Otra ventaja de este sistema es que puedes también generalizar un poco más tu UserService: Es posible que alguno de los campos faltantes acabe estando en el CSV, por lo que yo intentaría leer todos los campos del map (`if (map.containsKey(...)) {...}`) para saber si tengo que rellenarlos o no.